# Incorporating a custom Word Dictionary in iOS App

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, dictionary

I have two extremely related questions.

1. I have a custom-language dictionary added as an extension to Mac OSX Lion's builtin dictionary app. It's great. Is there any way I can include that in an app in iOS? Seems there isn't! The app ends in a .dictionary extension.
2. Is there a way to pull out the dictionary contents of a string from the built-in dictionary of iOS, and display it in my custom view?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure on the first one, but a dictionary in Objective-C works just like a dictionary in real life. So, if you have a dictionary entry "StackOverflow (n. stak - over - flow): A website for programmers to ask questions and receive answers", translating that into an Objective-C dictionary is very simple. The word, StackOverflow, would be your key, and "(n. stak - over - flow): A website for programmers to ask questions and receive answers" would be your object, wrapped as an NSString. You can use [myDictionary objectForKey:@"StackOverflow"]; to pull out the definition. You can use allKeysForObject: to get the key, as well. From there, displaying it an a UIView is trivial.